# Convert array of strings into multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, recursion

How to convert array of strings:

```
[
`ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People`,
 `ou=IT,ou=Employees,ou=People`,
`ou=Video,ou=Employees,ou=People`,
 `ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People` ,
`ou=aHR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People` ,`ou=HR2,ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People`,
]
```

into multi-dimensional like this
[image]

Comment: Use loops. Once you've got some code, and questions about said code, come on back and we'll try to help.

Comment: Post whatever is contained in your screenshot in your actual question, assuming it is an array layout. I can't actually see images on this site.

Comment: i'v got result http://joxi.ru/1A5XWQJhnPRoB2 . It was done by this code in the loop   $elements = getDn($raw_dn);
    $elements = array_values($elements);

    $string = '';
    $val = '';
    $closer = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
        if ($i == count($elements) - 1) {
            $val = $children . ']';
        }
        $string .= '["text"=>"' . $elements[$i] . '","children"=>' . $val . '';

        if ($i > 0) $closer .= ']';
    }
    $string .= $closer;

    eval("\$array = $string;");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = [
    'ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=IT,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=Video,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=aHR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=HR2,ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
];

$output = [];

foreach( $input as $line ) {
    // split by commas
    $parts = explode(',', $line);
    // remove 'ou='
    $parts = array_map(function($a){return preg_replace('/^ou=/', '', $a);}, $parts);
    // reverse
    $parts = array_reverse($parts);

    // assign the cur pointer to the base of the output array
    $cur = &$output;
    foreach($parts as $part) {
        // create the key if not exists
        if( ! key_exists($part, $cur) ) {
            $cur[$part] = [];
        }
        // assign the cur pointer to the current level in the array
        $cur = &$cur[$part];
    }
}
// unset the reference to avoid future problems if $cur were ever reused.
unset($cur);

var_dump($output);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["People"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Employees"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["HR"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["HR1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["HR2"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
        ["aHR1"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["IT"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Video"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### edit

You've nerd-sniped me. There is a recursive solution, and you want to consider the input array as a list of paths through the tree. So you'll want to traverse the tree along the given paths, adding missing nodes as necessary. Though really it works out almost exactly the same as the plain loop code.

```
$input = [
    'ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=IT,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=Video,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=aHR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=HR2,ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
];

function add_path_to_tree(&$root, $path) {
    $key = array_shift($path);

    if( ! key_exists($key, $root) ) {
        $root[$key] = [];
    }
    if( empty($path) ) { return; }
    return add_path_to_tree($root[$key], $path);
}

function solve_recurse($input) {
    $output = [];
    foreach( $input as $line ) {
        $parts = array_reverse(
            array_map(
                function($a){return preg_replace('/^ou=/', '', $a);},
                explode(',', $line)
            )
        );
        add_path_to_tree($output, $parts);
    }
    return $output;
}

var_dump(
    solve_recurse($input)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sammitch!! Actually I have put much efforts to solve the problem.At the beginning I'v got stuck in using recursion. And this way have not work out. Later I've asked question here

Comment: @игорь88 you could definitely solve this recursively, but once your problem moves away from trivial the recursive solution becomes far more complex to visualize, and this one's hurting my brain. [Probably something with trees?] Next time you post a question you should definitely include the code that you've tried so that we know you're not fishing for free code, and so that we have a starting point to help you out.

Comment: This is the answer. Leaving aside the meta rant about someone else using eval, which should have been expressed via comments and down votes to the offending answer, not as part of an otherwise useful answer. :)

Comment: Sammitch, thank you! Next time I will follow the rules.I apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: @salathe well now the offending answer was deleted so the meta rant just looks like the ravings of an insane person so I'm going to have to figure out how best to edit this :P

Answer (score 3):

Complex solution:

```
/**
 * Converts path into array (hierarchically)
 *
 * @param $arr
 *
 */
function pathToArray($arr){
    $result = [];

    $checkItem = function (&$keys, &$a) use(&$checkItem){
        foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($a[$v])) {
                $a[$v] = [];
            }
            unset($keys[$k]);
            if (!empty($keys)) $checkItem($keys, $a[$v]);
        }
    };

    foreach ($arr as $path) {
        $curren_arr = [];
        $keys = array_reverse(array_map(function($v){
            return str_replace('ou=', '', $v);
        }, explode(',', $path)));

        $checkItem($keys, $result);
    }

    return $result;
}

$arr = [
    'ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People', 'ou=IT,ou=Employees,ou=People',
    'ou=Video,ou=Employees,ou=People', 'ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People' ,
    'ou=aHR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People' ,'ou=HR2,ou=HR1,ou=HR,ou=Employees,ou=People',
];

print_r(pathToArray($arr));
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [People] => Array
        (
            [Employees] => Array
                (
                    [HR] => Array
                        (
                            [HR1] => Array
                                (
                                    [HR2] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )

                            [aHR1] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [IT] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Video] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rоman!!

Comment: @игорь88, you're welcome